# Sort array of objects by date property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

Hello guys I want to sort array by "**New_date**" but in some cases there is another object inside of main object with key "**New_date**". Do you know how could I sort array in this case?

```
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {

        a = new Date(a.New_date);
        b = new Date(b.New_date);
        return a>b ? -1 : a<b ? 1 : 0;
    });

arr= 
[0: {name:"Angel", data "random data", New_date: "2020-12-10"},  
 1: [0: {name:"Tom", data "random data"},
     1: {name:"Tom", data "random data"},
     New_date:"2020-11-10"],  
 2:name:"Angel", data "random data", New_date: "2020-09-10"}]
```

[image]

Comment: `return a.getTime() - b.getTime()`

Comment: ps.  Your sort will works too as long your define the array first, if your wanting descending sort, if you want a descending sort using getTime, just reverse the condition ->  `return b.getTime() - a.getTime()`..

Comment: Also, your sort-comparison function should not need to create new objects.  Simply compare them and return a value that is less than, equal to, or greater than zero.  You can easily sort on one or on multiple fields in this way.

Comment: Firstly, this has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery. You're using the plain JS `sort()` method. Secondly, could you provide an actual example of the array. The one in the question has a lot of syntax problems.

Comment: You are mixing arrays and objects. Please make sure that you give a valid example. The example you gave is not a valid javascript structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a correctly formatted array.

```js
let arr = [
  { name: "Angel", data: "random data", New_date: "2020-12-10" },
  { name: "Tom", data: "random data", New_date: "2019-11-10" },
  { name: "Tom", data: "random data", New_date: "2020-11-10" },
  { name: "Angel", data: "random data", New_date: "2020-09-10" },
]
console.log('ascending', arr.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.New_date) - new Date(b.New_date)))
console.log('descending', arr.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.New_date) - new Date(a.New_date)))
```

Comment: You solution works, but only if there is no other array inside with value of New_date.

Comment: You should have array of objects or array of arrays. Mixing those is not a good practice. You need to decide between those two options. You can always put those arrays inside of objects that contain New_date.